# VBA Access Specify Field Format for a Date/Time Field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having issues with changing the Field Format of a existing Data/Time Field.

I want to add a field called "Duration" to a table called "IncidentData" and change the field to show only the hour and minutes information such as "13:44"

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to set the format property of the field to Short Time or hh:nn.

[alt text http://ltd.remou.com/access/tableformat.png](http://ltd.remou.com/access/tableformat.png)